# List all items and highlight those which are in a given category

Tags: php, eloquent, relationship

So ... I got those two eloquent models and a pivot table:

```
## Categories ##
- ID
- title
belongsToMany(Items)

## Items ##
- ID
- title
belongsToMany(Categories)

## Items_Categories ##
- items ID
- categories ID
```

I need a list of ALL items and highlight those which are in a given category.

```
# Example #

## Categorie #1 ##
- Item #1 (is in category)
- Item #2 
- Item #3 (is in category)
- Item #4 (is in category)
- Item #5

## Category #2 ##
- Item #1 (is in category)
- Item #2 
- Item #3
- Item #4 (is in category)
- Item #5
```

I feeld like I did this a hundred times in the past, but I can't figure out how to set this up. :-(

If there's a better solution on setting up those models / relationships I'm game.

```php
// Get a single category with containing items
$category = Catgegory::whereNull('is_deleted')
    ->where('id', 1)
    ->with('items')
    ->first();

// Get all items
$allItems = Item::whereNull('is_deleted')
    ->get();


// Now what?
foreach ($allItems as $item) {
    // Compare with category items?!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a method in items model to check whether is item category equals to that category or not. so you can check it like so:

The method in the item model that checks the category_id:

```
  public function isInCategory($category_id){

      //get all $category_ids
      $category_ids = $this->categories()->pluck('id')->toArray();

     //check if $category_id exists in $category_ids array
      if(is_array($category_ids) && in_array($category_id,$category_ids))
          return true;

      return false;

    }
```

Or you can do it with this method

```
 public function isInCategory($category_id){

   return $this->categories->contains($category_id);
}
```

Both methods are working fine. But remember to write this method in **Item model**.

So you can use it in your code like this:

```
// Get a single category with containing items
$category = Catgegory::whereNull('is_deleted')
    ->where('id', 1)
    ->with('items')
    ->first();

// Get all items
$allItems = Item::whereNull('is_deleted')
    ->get();


// check the category id
foreach ($allItems as $item) {
    $item->isInCategory($category->id) // returns true or false
}
```

Comment: This seems like the way to go. But my problem is that there's no field "category_id" in the items model. It's an belongsToMany relationship with a pivot table.

Every item can be in multiple categories and every categorie has multiple items.

Something like this:
`public function isInCategory($category_id){
    return $this->category->id == $category_id;
}`

Comment: @Chriss sry my bad I did not pay attention to that part wait a sec I come Up with new solution

Comment: that worked like a charm. Thank you so much! - I owe you a beer.

Comment: @Chriss don't mention it. thanks but it would be more helpful if you cast an upvote for my answer as well. thank you

Comment: Already did, but I'm still at a reputation below 15, so it doesn't show. :-/

Comment: @Chriss No, you just mark it as the best answer. an upvote (up arrow) would be nice. thank u :)

Comment: yep. That's what I did. I got this notification: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." :-)